# After I unbind the Trackpoint driver (psmouse), the driver re-bound when I press it. What causes this?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, thinkpad, sysfs

For background information, see [Manual driver binding and unbinding](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/).

I can unbind the Trackpoint driver on my Thinkpad:

```
$ cd /sys/bus/serio/drivers/psmouse/
$ ls -l
total 0
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Dec  5 20:04 bind
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Dec  5 19:19 bind_mode
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Dec  5 19:19 description
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Dec  5 19:19 module -> ../../../../module/psmouse
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Dec  5 19:19 serio1 -> ../../../../devices/platform/i8042/serio1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Dec  5 20:14 serio2 -> ../../../../devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Dec  5 19:19 uevent
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Dec  5 20:07 unbind
$ echo serio2 | sudo tee unbind
serio2
$ ls
bind  bind_mode  description  module  serio1  uevent  unbind
```

After I click one of the trackpoint buttons, or move it, the Trackpoint starts working again.  This is because the driver gets bound again:

```
$ ls
bind  bind_mode  description  module  serio1  serio2  uevent  unbind
```

What causes the driver to be bound again?

- Kernel: 4.11.8-200.fc25.x86_64
- OS: Fedora Workstation 25
- Hardware: Thinkpad X201

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is related to how Linux detects PS/2 devices which are plugged in after the system booted.  ("hotplugging").

PS/2 ports were designed in an era when hotplugging was not as well supported.  E.g. early Microsoft Windows did not support hotplugging PS/2 ports.

I suspect there is no hotplug signal, or it cannot be relied on.  So Linux can just listen for *any* data on unbound PS/2 ports.  When it receives some data, it must re-probe the port.

At least it's a nice theory.  However I don't see the same thing happen if I unbind the combined touchpad/trackpoint device on a different laptop (Dell Latitude E5450).  I have to manually bind the driver again; it doesn't magically start working again e.g. when I press a button.